# How to Custom UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm a newbie in swift, and i try to custom `UITableViewCell`, i see many tutorial in youtube and internet. But i can't do it, i tried to fix a lot of way but nothing is change.
here is my code :

```
class movieViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var categories = ["Action", "Drama", "Science Fiction", "Kids", "Horror"]


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnMenu: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btnMenu.target = self.revealViewController()
    btnMenu.action = Selector("revealToggle:")

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 200
    self.tableView.registerClass(CategoryRow.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return categories[section]
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryRow
    cell.labelA.text = self.categories[indexPath.row]
    cell.labelB.text = self.categories[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

**CategoryRow.swift:**

```
    class CategoryRow: UITableViewCell {
    var labelA: UILabel!
    var labelB: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

and my bug :

[image]

Comment: Where are you creating `labelA` and `labelB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem that you don't have xib. And you just declare your label but you don't init it. So `labelA` and `labelB` will nil. it make crash.

If you don't want xib, You must implement two function in `CategoryRow` like code below:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.labelA = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height))
//Same here for labelB
    self.contentView.addSubview(labelA)
}
```

Another way is you create xib `UITableCiewCell` with name same with your class. And set this cell is your class. You design `labelA` and `labelB` in this xib and drage outlet into class. And you modify in `viewDidLoad`

```
 self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "nameYourxib"), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Comment: OMG you save me , and how about if i have .xib?

Comment: how about if i change label -> UIImageView? and don't use xib?

Comment: Yes, I'm Vietnamese. Same with user label. You must calculate your frame of UIImageView. And it seem complicated with multiple size of iPhone.

Comment: do you have skype or facebook address?

Comment: vienvtl_89 Here is my skype.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't linked labelA inStoryboard. 
[Creating an Outlet Connection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocate the labelA or labelB. Thats why show the error. Connect your label with you UI like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

@vien vu answer is right but what to do without XIB ?? [Here](http://developerclouds.com/2016/03/23/table-view-custom-cell-with-self-sizing/) is the complete solution for Custom cell in swift

Answer (score -3):

You need to add delegate a datasource in viewDidLoad

```
viewDidLoad() {
  self.tableView.delegate = self
  self.tableView.datasource = self
}
```

and you need to create the labelA and labelB by outlets not variables. Hold control and drag from Storyboard to the corisponding file and let go, choose outlet and give it the name labelA and labelB

Comment: If delegate wasn't set, the delegate methods wouldn't be called. Overriding `viewDidLoad` method and not calling `super.viewDidLoad()` would get you bitten by bugs. The labels part is correct.